# What is the cardinality of $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\Bbb R^n$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the cardinality of the infinite union of R^n, that is n=1 to infinity? 
Also is there a generalization for arbitrary sets?

Comment: Are you regarding these successive sets as nested, disjoint, or what? The question doesn't make sense without more information...

Comment: how can they be nested?

Answer (score 2):

$|\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb R^n|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\mathbb R^n|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\mathbb R|=\aleph_0\cdot c=c$.

You can generalize from this computation.

Remark: Cardinal arithmetic works best when accepting AC. I'm not sure what can be said about your question in the absence of choice.

Comment: In the case of $\Bbb R$ itself, it's a particular set, and we can prove this equality (although not the way you present it, rather the way I wrote above with injections and Cantor-Bernstein). In the general case this sort of equality implies the axiom of choice (as it implies $|A\times A|=|A|$ for infinite sets).

Comment: Thanks Asaf. Looking at your answer I should have figured the answer to my remark myself....

Comment: Of course, you don't need a Ph.D. to figure out that answer. B.Sc. should suffice... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

We can show, assuming the axiom of choice, that if $A$ is an infinite set then $$\left|\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}A^n\right|=|A|.$$

The proof goes like that: using the axiom of choice we can show that $|A\times A|=|A|$, therefore by induction $|A^n|=|A|$ for every $n\in\Bbb N$ (well, except $n=0$, but that's fine). Now we have a countable union of sets of size $|A|$, so its cardinality is $\aleph_0\cdot|A|=|A|$.

In some cases we have better tools that we can utilize, for example in the case of $A=\Bbb N$ we can use the fact that every natural number has a unique decomposition into prime numbers to construct a very nice bijection.

In the case of $\Bbb R$ we can easily show, without the axiom of choice, that $|\Bbb R|\leq|\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\Bbb R^n|\leq|\Bbb{R^N}|\leq|\Bbb R|$, therefore, by Cantor-Bernstein, equality ensues.

The general case is more difficult and it requires the axiom of choice.